# Get dataset of parent, while clicking on child

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dataset

I have the following code, in which I have a button with `data` attribute and div inside of it, I want to get the dataset of button, no matter how deep is the target inside of a child.

```
export default function App() {
  const handler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        data-id="myDataId"
        onClick={handler}
        style={{ 
          height: 200, 
          width: 200, 
          backgroundColor: "green" 
        }}
      >
        Bruh
        <div
          style={{
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            backgroundColor: "red"
          }}
        />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this example, my console gives undefined when I click inside of the div, but if Iclick to button, it gives my `data` attribute.

I tried to use `event.path`, but it didn't give any results.

Is there any generic way to get the dataset of my button?.

Here is the fully working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-breeze-e1lh2?file=/src/App.js:23-535

Comment: You'll probably need two different click handlers. One for the parent element, and another for the child. In the child handler, you can use this to get the parent's data attribute - `e.target.parentNode.dataset.id`

Comment: Hmm, is there any other generic way to that?

Comment: I didn't get the question you need to console bruh when the button is clicked ?

Comment: @SachinYadav no I need to console content of my `data-id`, in this case it's "aaaaaa" :D

Comment: let me change it to the normal name

Comment: So is the expected output "aaaaa" when the div is clicked ?

Comment: yap, I edited my question, now it's "myDataId" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I should've gotten the dataset from the `currentTarget` not from the `target`.

The difference is that the `target` comes from the exact element on which was performed click, and the `currentTarget` is the element on which onClick was set.

```
const handler = (e) => {
  console.log(e.currentTarget.dataset.id); // instead of e.target
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import "./styles.css";
import {useRef} from 'react'
export default function App() {
  const myContainer = useRef(null);
  const handler = (myContainer) => {
    console.log(myContainer.current.closest(".parent").getAttribute("data-id"))
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        data-id="aaaaaaa"
        className = "parent"
        onClick={() => handler(myContainer)}
        style={{ height: 200, width: 200, backgroundColor: "green" }}
      >
        Bruh
        <div
        ref={myContainer}
          style={{
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            backgroundColor: "red"
          }}
        />
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it can work for this particular case, but is there a way to do this for example with 5 nested elements deep?

Comment: I have edited the answer please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parentElement` property of the target.

If you don't know how deep the target might be, you can loop through ancestors until you find it.
There is an example:

```js
const handler = (e) => {
  let target = e.target
  while (target && target.tagName != 'BUTTON') target = target.parentElement

  console.log(target?.dataset.id)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this not stable, it can cause an infinite loop :/

Comment: I just edited the code to provide a more specific and stable answer.